# function find loop VBA code to locate and get informations from cells based on creteria in an other clomn

Tags: vba, excel

I'm New in VBA Programmation , i'm looking for code VBA in excel that can make This : 
1 : with an input box i can enter  the Action Number 
2 : get the Action number from the input box and go to sheet1 locate all rows with this number 
3 :sum the values of celles in colomn B based on the same action number 
and get out the reponse in a MSg box (" action number , sume (values clomn B)).
4 : the same thing for values in colomn C

[image]

i hope it's clear

think you

Comment: sounds like you have a good start on the requirements.  My advice is to start at step one, and once that's implemented move on to step 2, 3, and wrap it up with step 4.  If you get jammed up on any specific step, please post what you tried, what worked, what didn't, and your expected result.  Putting in a little effort will go a long way in getting help.

Comment: ok i well do my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lucky I wrote a similar Sub today :)
It does not solve your problem but you do not have to start on an empty page.
Play with it, add it to your code and adjust it where needed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim tmp As Integer

'get the last row in this sheet (column A)
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

tmp = 0
'run from 1 to the last row
For i = 1 To LastRow
    'search for matches
    If Cells(i, 1).Text = TexBbox1.value Then
        'if found, add to tmp
        tmp = tmp + Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next

MsgBox "here is your number" & tmp

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you , i well tray one's hande at doing with this. and i well give a response this afternoon

Comment: whay when i change the variable type  ( numaction )  from double to variant a get 0 in the reponse ??

Comment: the only reason i can think of:
"A Variant is a special data type that can contain any kind of data except fixed-length String data."

Comment: I'm not sure where the error is but you can try to convert the variant to string (CStr()) or to a double (Cdbl()).

Comment: i would like to chekck the data input by user , so  i did this but it does not work :  i creat a ne variable " numaction  Variant"   then , numaction = InputBox("enter the N°") , after that insert the verification with (  isnumeric )  it  work when numaction is as double but i can't do the data input vérification . and when i change the variable type from double to variant i can do the verification but the response is always 0 ... so ?

Comment: what i meant: numaction as variant
and then: if Cells(x,y) = CDbl(numaction) Then

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim numaction As Variant
Dim LastRow As Double
Dim tmp1 As Double
Dim tmp2 As Double
Dim tmp3 As Double
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
numaction = InputBox("entrer le numero d'action", "Frais Mosolf")
With ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    enter code here
End With
tmp1 = 0
tmp2 = 0
tmp3 = 0
For i = 1 To LastRow
If Cells(i, 1).Value = numaction Then    enter code here
tmp1 = tmp1 + Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value    enter code here
tmp2 = tmp2 + Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value
tmp3 = tmp3 + Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value 
End If
```

Next

```
 codMsgBox "here is your numbers" & " " & tmp1 & " " & tmp2 & " " & tmp3
End Sube
```

whay when i change as double to as variant in numaction vriable type , a get the response 0 0 0 it's mean's tha tmp1 ,tmp2,tmp3  get 0